# Correct preposition to go with "inquiry"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to figure out which preposition to use together with "inquiry". For example, take the following sentence:

> I have asked Bob, but he doesn't know.

Now I'd like to express the same using "inquiry":

> A previous inquiry [insert correct preposition here] Bob did not yield any new insights.

What is the correct choice? If the object was an institution I'd probably use "at", but that doesn't sound right for a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *inquire **with*** or ***of*** (someone), ***at*** (a place), or ***into*** (something), so:

> *A previous inquiry **with / of** Bob did not yield any new insights.*

Comment: These sound unidiomatic to me. It's probably the incongruity of the hyper-formal and – well, Bob.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Both [_'inquire of'_](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=inquire_V+padv+of_PREP) and [_'inquire with'_](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=inquire_V+padv+with_PREP) are correct (though the latter is less popular), though they do sound a bit formal - but then that's because of 'inquire' itself...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point - it does sound significantly better with Robert or Charles.

Comment: One could also say *“an inquiry **to** Bob”* (or to an organization), e.g. *“An inquiry to Sen. Robert Robertson (’s office) was not answered by press time.”*